# VBA - Copy first three characters from string into another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I struggle with splitting the first three characters from a cell and insert them into another cell as a seperate string.

My (example) input:

```
A

A123456
A133457
B123456
B133457
...
```

What I want:

```
A            B
A123456      A12
A133457      A13
B123456      B12
B133457      B13
...          ...
```

What I tried:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("summary")

For Each cell In ws.Range("A").Cells
    cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
    Next cell
```

This can't work since I'd overwrite the value in all the cells A which I don't want to. Can someone provide help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in Excel without VBA, you can use formula:
=LEFT(A1,3)

With VBA, you can do the following:

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("A:A").Cells
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
Next cell
```

Note that I have amended the range.  You probably want to limit is further as "A:A" will take a while.

The offset function says "use the cell 1 to the right of the current cell".

Comment: Thank you very much. In the example I said I needed the right cell for the new values, but I need the left cell (so all the values from cell A are in cell B and the cutted ones shall go into cell A). Hope you understand what I mean. How can I do this?

Comment: @KevinD Just insert a column to the left of column A, then adapt either the VBA or worksheet formula answers to reflect that

Comment: Formula: =LEFT(B1,3)

VBA:
For Each cell In ws.Range("B:B").Cells
    cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Left(cell.Value, 3)
Next cell